# Saving ouput in the form of array using matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
% Find a VISA-GPIB object.
obj1 = instrfind('Type', 'visa-gpib', 'RsrcName', 'GPIB8::1::INSTR', 'Tag', '');

% Create the VISA-GPIB object if it does not exist
% otherwise use the object that was found.
if isempty(obj1)
      obj1 = visa('TEK', 'GPIB8::1::INSTR');
else
      fclose(obj1);
      obj1 = obj1(1);
end

% Connect to instrument object, obj1.
fopen(obj1);

t = timer;

t.TasksToExecute = 3;

t.Period = 30;

t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';

t.TimerFcn = @(myTimerObj, thisEvent)disp(query(obj1,'CALCulate:SPECtrum:MARKer0:Y?'));

start(t)
```

This is my program where I have to save the output values which displays 
`Query('CALCulate:SPECtrum:MARKer0:Y?')` in a array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a variable to hold the outputs of `query(obj1, 'CALCulate:SPECtrum:MARKer0:Y?')`. You can then append to this variable from within the timer callback function.

```
%// Initialize a cell array (because I'm not sure of your datatype)
results = {};

%// Define a function to be called when the timer fires
function timerCallback(varargin)
    newresult = query(obj1,'CALCulate:SPECtrum:MARKer0:Y?');

    %// Display the result (like you currently are)
    disp(newresult)

    %// Append the result to your results container
    results{end+1} = newresult;
end

%// Then set your timer callback
t = timer('TasksToExecute', 3, ...
          'Period', 30, ...
          'ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', ...
          'TimerFcn', @timerCallback);

start(t)
```

All of your other setup code would remain the same.

Comment: when I use that query my output values would be in the form of float !!

Comment: @SaiSandyuthGandham What do you expect? This code does not cast anything to any type (because I used a cell array).

Comment: sir , It is showing error at function saying that " Usage might be invalid matlab syntax "  !!

Comment: Do cell array handles every data type ? And what does " varargin " indicates ??

Comment: @SaiSandyuthGandham You will have to put the above code within a function block in order to be executed since I have a subfunction in there. `varargin` represents a variable number of inputs.